# Continuous typing between EditTexts

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 3 `EditTexts (et1, et2, et3)`, arranged next to each other, with `maxLength` of **'1'**.

My requirement is:

1. When a letter is typed in the edit text (can contain only 1 char, as max length is 1), the cursor goes automatically to next EditText.
2. Similarly, when user clicks back on et2, the cursor should go to et1.
3. The edittext will be filled in sequential manner. That is first the first one, then second, then third.
   So even if the user clicks on the third edit text box & the first and second text box is empty, then cursor goes to the first edittext. 
   In simple terms, the cursor will go to last empty edit text.

How can this be achieved programmaticaly.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is to use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

You can use something like this:

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         et2.requestFocus;
         et1.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});

et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        String textBeforeChange;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
          textBeforeChange = s.subSequence(start, start + count).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              if (s.subSequence(start, start + count).length == 0 
                   && textBeforeChange .length >= 1)
            et1.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is more save you ask for the edittext to clear the focus before ask another one to request it : )

Answer (score 0):

Here is the aswer for your questions:

```
    //findViewById and bla bla bla...

    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {



        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            editText1.setSelection(count); //set the cursor after the last character

        }




        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }




        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



            if(editText1.length() == 1){ //check for number of characters

                editText1.clearFocus();

                editText2.requestFocus();

            }



        }




    });

    editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {



        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            editText2.setSelection(count);


            if(editText1.length() != 1){ //check if previous editText is empty

                editText2.clearFocus();

                editText1.requestFocus();

            }



        }




        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }




        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



            if(editText2.length() == 1){

                editText2.clearFocus();

                editText3.requestFocus();

            }



        }




    });


    editText3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {



        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            editText3.setSelection(count);


            if(editText1.length() != 1){ //check if first editText is empty

                editText3.clearFocus();

                editText1.requestFocus();

            }



            else if(editText2.length() != 1){ //check if second editText is empty

                editText3.clearFocus();

                editText2.requestFocus();

            }



        }




        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }




        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



            if(editText3.length() == 1){

                //Do something after the last editText was typed

            }



        }




    });








    //user pressed the back button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){



        if(editText2.isFocused()){

            editText2.clearFocus();

            editText1.requestFocus();

        } 



        else if(editText3.isFocused(){

            editText3.clearFocus();

            editText2.requestFocus();

        } 



        else super.onBackPressed();



    }
```